# How to crease original edges after an extrusion?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Using geometry nodes, take a cube, extrude individual faces and add a subdivision.

How to crease original edges only for the subdivision?

Top and side outputs of the extrusion are related to faces, so they are not discriminant about the edges I want to crease.

The way I've found to do it is to split the mesh before the extrusion, capture original edges (boundary edges) and use it for the subdivision.

[image]

But this is an heavy calculation just for selecting edges: is there a better way to do it?

Example file (4.0):

[image]

To clarify:

I want to crease independently original and top edges (the two on the left) but not the side edges (the one on the right):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simplified the example to capture the heart of the problem:

[image]

[image]

The same selection of edges you can get by simply selecting the edges that were not created by extrusion:

[image]

Comment: So there is a "guaranty" that original indexes are stable after the extrusion?

Comment: @lemon I think it's a safe assumption, based on my experience in geonodes and python API. Unfortunately the documentation is so scarce I think you can't do almost anything with absolute certainty it will never break, even Edge Split modifier changed temporarily in v. 3.6 (it wasn't disconnecting loops of edges of e.g. a curve converted to a mesh without profile) - reverted to old behavior in v 4.0. Or does the documentation give you the guarantee for the captured attribute carrying behavior after merging by distance? Also not, unfortunately.