# What's the simplest way on a Geometry Nodes extrusion to keep ONLY the "top" and "side" of the extrusion and delete the original mesh part?

Tags: geometry-nodes, extrude

I have this rectangle, which is a result of the extrusion of the leftmost vertical edge:

[image]

I wanna delete that original edge after the extrusion.

Basically wanna end up with the inverse (mirror) of this:

[image]

I can't find the correct combination of boolean math/ delete geometry node settings/ separate geometry nodes... or what it is to achieve it. Every combination deleted everything but the original edge exclusively. And the worst is this seems so basic. I'm losing my mind.

help

Comment: This is similar to this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308134/how-to-crease-original-edges-after-an-extrusion. You should base the selection on the edge indices.

Comment: With the "inverse" you mean "mirrored"? Or inverse like Boolean inversion "not"? Because real inversion would mean, everything that originally stays will be deleted, and the only thing that stays is what was deleted before - resulting in only the vertical edge being moved to the right, which is nothing you need an extrusion for. If you mean mirrored, use a _Compare_ node to check if _Index_ = 0, then use the result as _Selection_ for the _Delete Geometry_ node: [mirrored version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEFov.jpg) (you can even leave it at "All" in this case instead of "Only Edges & Faces").

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yours was the simplest way, thank you